# PHP curl not working, Object moved to here

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the data/html of this url `http://www.mahoor.com/` but i get **Object moved to here** returned.  I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` now nothing is returned.

```
    function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data("http://www.mahoor.com");
print_r($returned_content);
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this site is looking for a cookie in the header. You can fix by adding this to your function:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Cookie:langcookie=en; currentcurr=USD',
      ));
```

I don't know if you'd want to change the lang and currency values.

Comment: You can do this more generically by enabling the cookie engine, and not having to know any of the given URL's cookies:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'');`